Does the Banach space of controlled rough paths $\mathcal{D}_X^{2\alpha}$ depend on the full rough path $(X, \mathbb{X})$ or only on the Path $X$?
I am following the book A Course on Rough Paths, by Friz & Hairer, and have a question regarding controlled rough paths and the Banach space structure associated with them. Specifically, I'm trying to understand the dependence of the Banach space on the rough path.
Definition of a Controlled Rough Path:
Definition 4.6. Given a path $X \in C^\alpha([0,T],V)$, we say that $Y \in C^\alpha([0,T],\bar{W})$ is controlled by $X$ if there exists $Y' \in C^\alpha([0,T],\mathcal{L}(V, \bar{W}))$ so that the remainder term $R^Y$ given implicitly through the relation
$$
Y_{s,t} = Y_s' X_{s,t} + R^Y_{s,t},
$$
satisfies $\|R^Y\|_{2\alpha} < \infty$. This defines the space of controlled rough paths,
$$
(Y, Y') \in \mathcal{D}_X^{2\alpha}([0,T], \bar{W}).
$$
Banach Space Norm:
The space $\mathcal{D}_X^{2\alpha}$ becomes a Banach space with the norm given by
$$
    \|(Y, Y')\|_{X,2\alpha} := |Y_0| + |Y_0'| + \|Y'\|_\alpha + \|R^Y\|_{2\alpha}.
$$
In Remark 4.8 of their book, the authors state that the Banach space $\mathcal{D}_X^{2\alpha}$ relies crucially on the choice of the rough path $\boldsymbol{X}$, where $\boldsymbol{X} = (X,\mathbb{X}) \in \mathcal{C}^\alpha$.
Question:
Does the Banach space $\mathcal{D}_X^{2\alpha}$ depend on the specific choice of the rough path $\boldsymbol{X} = (X, \mathbb{X})$, or does it depend only on the path $X$? I ask this, because neither in the definition of the controlled rough path space or the Banach space norm do I see a reference to the second-level path $\mathbb{X}$.

That's a pertinent observation. Indeed, the Banach space $\mathcal{D}^{2\alpha}_X$ depends only on the original path $X$, not on its lift. I believe the authors mention the enhanced path $\mathbf{X} = (X,\mathbb{X})$ because the concept of controlled rough paths arises in the context of rough path integration. In this setting, we start with a rough path $\mathbf{X}$ and then extract the path component $X$. The regularity of this path $X$ determines the corresponding Banach space $\mathcal{D}^{2\alpha}_X$.
